# Getting different answer on JQuery foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, foreach

I was trying to read all the values in a map/jsonobject. Following is my function call,

```
a ={"a":{"b":"c"}}
result= test(a,'a')    
console.log(result)
```

And the function is,

```
function test(jsonObj,name){

    main = ""
    if(jQuery.type(jsonObj)==='object'){
        $.each(Object.keys(jsonObj),function(){
             main += test(jsonObj[this],name+'_'+this)  
        });
   }else{
       main +=jsonObj;
   }   
   return main
}
```

When I execute the above script I am getting an ouput `c`.

Later I modified the function a little,

```
function test(jsonObj,name){        
    main = ""
    if(jQuery.type(jsonObj)==='object'){
        $.each(Object.keys(jsonObj),function(){
            resp = test(jsonObj[this],name+'_'+this) //this line added
            main +=resp
        });
   }else{
       main +=jsonObj;
   }   
   return main
}
```

Now I am getting `cccc` as my output. I am not able to understand the behaviour. Why am I getting different(unexpected) result when I introduced a new variable?

Comment: in our old code you are calling test function again and main = " " reset the variable value. in second code main variable is just appended with resp variable so u are getting cccc as our output

Comment: just add console.log(main) in your $.each function and debug the code u will come to know the difference between the two o/p's

Comment: In my first code I am not initialling the main inside the loop. I am just appending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `main` is declared in global scope. Because of that, the recursion in the function just adds new results to it.

By declaring your variable with `var` keyword, you limit its scope to the function

```
function test(jsonObj, name) {        
    var main = "";
    if (jQuery.type(jsonObj)==='object') {
        $.each(Object.keys(jsonObj),function() {
            resp = test(jsonObj[this],name+'_'+this); //this line added
            main +=resp;
        });
    } else {
        main +=jsonObj;
    }
    return main;
};

a ={"a":{"b":"c"}};
result= test(a,'a');    
console.log(result); // outputs 'c'
```

I've also fixed some small typos in your code, such as missing semicolons etc.

Comment: Thank you Petr. Adding Var to the variable main solved my problem.

Comment: In the first and second the scope of `main` remains the same. Then why we get different output? It will be great if you explain me in bit more details?

Comment: I accept your answer later, so that someone else may be interested to provide more info on this thread.

Comment: Checkout this answer for more info on `var` keyword: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it